# mySQL compatible string crypting between mySQL 5.7 and 8.0

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, mysql-8.0

I have an old php project written to save data on dbase with mySQL 5.7 and to save the password it use DES_ENCRYPT ().

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `t` (
  `q` varchar(257) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO t(q) values(DES_ENCRYPT('mypassword'));
```

I want to use the same code in another server where mySQL 8.0 is and it doesn't work because it seems DES_ENCRYPT () is obsolete.

I have tryed with AES_ENCRYPT or MD5, but mySQL 5.7 don't work (maybe because it's a varchar)... I thought to use HEX but it's too easy decrypt.

So, which is the best way to encrypt a string in a varchar field without drastically changing the code and being able to use it at the same time for both mysql?

Comment: AES works both on mysql 8.0 and 5.7 (and earlier) (but it obviously cannot decrypt existing DES data, if that is your concern). Please share the AES-code you tried, and the error message or invalid result you get (e.g. different behaviour on your servers)

Comment: I have this message "#1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'AES_ENCRYPT'" at the moment I'm using phpmyadmin to test